# Why does this method of solving the equation of SHM work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I was learning about second order differential equations,  to be exact,  this is the equation-
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = - \frac{k} {m} x$$
And the method I came across was to equate x to $e^{at} $,  but we consider a to be constant, and a comes out to be an imaginary number,  and we use Euler's formula to get the solution...  But shouldn't we consider a to be a function rather than a constant?

Comment: This is an ansatz. The key point is that exponentials are preserved, up to scalar multiples, upon differentiation. So if you're seeking a function whose second derivative is a multiple of itself, exponentials would be a good place to start looking. Substituting this guess puts a simple constraint on the constant. In general, this is just the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: @symplectomorphic That I  understand, but why aren't we differentiating a,  how can we be sure that it's a constant and not a function?

Comment: Because the ODE you are looking at is an eigenvalue problem of the form $Tf = \lambda f$. An eigenvalue is strictly a constant.

Comment: @Mattos Oh,  okay..

Comment: @Shahe: we are *assuming* a function of the form $x(t)=e^{at}$, where $a$ is a constant. the fact that $a$ is a constant is an *assumption*. we assume it because we know that the derivative of $e^{at}$ is $ae^{at}$ -- a multiple of the original function -- which makes $e^{at}$ precisely the kind of function that might work here.

Comment: @symplectomorphic That is not true,  if I assume a to be a function, then I'd need to use the chain rule which will. lead to a derivative of a  being part of the equation

Comment: you are not reading what I'm saying. we *assume* $a$ is a constant *because* differentiating the function $t\mapsto e^{at}$ gives a multiple of itself.

Comment: @symplectomorphic but shouldn't $\frac{dx} {dt}  = ae^{at} (a + t\frac{da}{dt} ) $